# How to templatize C++ constructor for perfect forwarding

Tags: c++, templates, perfect-forwarding

I know how to create a global function that forwards arguments to class ctor using variadic templates (its similar to make_shared<> for shared_ptr template class):

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
T Create (Args&&... args)
{
  return T(args...);  // RVO takes place here
}
```

Is it possible to use similar approach to create template for static factory method inside the class? I want to use similar variadic templates syntax to forward all arguments combinations to all possible constructors (I'd like to NOT overload or explicitly link all possible ctors to static methods and just use the templates & compiler to do this work)
i.e. in pseudocode (!)

```
class Class {
public: 
static Class create(Args&&... args) 
{
     Class(args...);
}
Class(int) {} // ctor 1
Class(int, float) {} // ctor 2 
//... etc
```

to have similar forwarding of arguments

If I use variadic template directly it looks like this

```
template <typename... Args>
class Class {
public:
    static Class create(Args&&... args)
    {
        return Class(args...);
    }
    Class(int) {} // ctor 1
    Class(int, float) {} // ctor 2
};
```

but it gives ugly usage syntax, where I need explicitly provide types to the template...

```
int main()
{
    Class<int,float> a = Class<int,float>::create(1,2);
}
```

Can it be just like this ??

```
Class a = Class::create(1,2);
```

Comment: @Quentin you mean to provide n static functions for each of n constructors? doesn't it break the Dont Repeat Yourself principle? If only we could ask the compilers somehow to generate all variations automagically...

Comment: Which part of your code doesn't work? Just add `template <typename ...Args>`?

Comment: @barney So I misunderstood. But why wouldn't you use the constructors directly ?

Comment: @KerrekSB in top example its global function Create that is templatized to nicely bind to every possible ctor using argument list. But I'd like to have a static method inside the class to have this nice syntax: Class instance = Class::Create(15, 15.5f);  and I want to write it only once using templates some how but not sure how to do so (and even is it possible at all)

Comment: @Quentin of course I can use constructors but I'd like to use named constructor pattern (to have one static method Class inst = Class::create(...); )

Comment: [OT] I don't see any *perfect* forwarding right now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just make the `create` function a template rather than the class:

```
class Class {
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    static Class create(Args&&... args)
    {
         //actually do perfect forwarding
        return Class(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    Class(int) {} // ctor 1
    Class(int, float) {} // ctor 2
};
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/720aca9e6ab5034d)

Comment: wow thanks that really works :) so simple and intuitive! I hoped that templating could be done for the individual class's method.

Answer (score 3):

> Can it be just like this ??
>
> `Class a = Class::create(1,2);`

No, function templates can deduce their arguments, but you wrote `Class` as a class template and you cannot deduce template arguments for class templates.

You cannot just say `Class` without saying which specialization of `Class` you mean, and you cannot create a variable of type `Class`, because `Class` is not a type, it's a template, i.e. a family of possible types.

You can create a free function to do it though:

```
template<typename... Args>
  inline
  Class<typename std::decay<Args>::type...>
  create_Class(ARgs&&... args)
  {
    return Class<typename std::decay<Args>::type...>{ std::forward<Args>(args)... };
  }
```

N.B. I added perfect forwarding, which you mentioned in your question title but failed to use anywhere.

Now you can do:

```
auto a = create_Class(1, 2);
```

This will create a `Class<int, int>` object.

But maybe you didn't want to make `Class` a template in the first place?

Comment: thanks for the great example, I'll study it. So the problem is that classes cannot (obviously) do argument deduction, but global functions are able to do so. Btw I discovered it's possible to define template for individual class method! See neighbor answer. Thanks to @TartanLlama for the answer.

Comment: No, that's not the problem. All function templates can do argument deduction, not just global functions. The problem was that you were trying to use `Class` like a type, but you defined it as a template, which is not a type. You wrote `Class a` which is not valid if `Class` is a template (which `Class<T>` do you mean? `Class<int> a`? Or `Class<double, char> a`? Or something else?), and you wrote `Class::create(1, 2)` which is not valid either (which `Class<T>` are you trying to call a member function of? `Class<int>::create(1, 2)`? Or `Class<double, char>::create(1, 2)`? Or something else?)

Comment: So if I refer to global function template create_Class(arg1, arg2) - it is valid reference to type so compiler deduces type from the arguments. But if I refer to class template Class without explicit mention of the type specialization - the compiler just doesn't have enough information for the deduction, right?

Comment: No, not really. If you refer to create_Class(arg1, arg2) then you don't mention any types. It's a function template so the compiler deduces the argument types from the call, and it deduces the return type from the arguments. But you're not referring to any types, you're calling a function. `Class<int>` is a type, `create_Class(arg1, arg2)` is a function call expression.